# All combinations

Tags: probability, combinations

I am figuring out some "easy" math calculation for my thesis. This is something I've learned somewhere in highschool but I can't quite remember how it's done. Maybe you guys can help me with this problem....

So I have 8 entities, lets say $A_1, A_2, ..., A_7, A_8$. All the entities can either hold one of the 3 values -1, 0 or +1. Assume that there should always be at two $A_i$ that hold a value of -1 or +1, thus there can never be more that six $A_i$ that hold a  value of 0. How many combinations are there. Note that in every combination of $n$ number of combinations every $A_i$ can be used once. For example:

OK:

$A_1=+1$, $A_2=+1$, $A_3=+1$, $A_4=+1$, $A_5=+1$, $A_6=+1$, $A_7=+1$, $A_8=+1$

$A_1= \ 0 $, $A_2=+1$, $A_3=+1$, $A_4=0$, $A_5=+1$, $A_6=+1$, $A_7=+1$, $A_8=+1$

NOT OK:

$A_1=0 $, $A_2=0$, $A_3=0$, $A_4=0$, $A_5=0$, $A_6=0$, $A_7=0$, $A_8=1$

or

$A_1=1 $, $A_1=0$, $A_1=1$, $A_4=0$

This should be common knwoledge to me, but I can seem to figure it out. Your help is much appreciated.

Yours,

Comment: When you exchange the values of $A_1$ and $A_2$ in your second OK example, i.e. $A_1=+1, A_2=0$ and have $A_3,\ldots,A_8$ stay the same, do you consider this the same configuration as your example or a different one? I ask because you mentioned "combinations" a few times, and combinations usually don't consider the order of the things they select.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say with your second "NOT OK" example. Is the issue that there are just 4 terms instead of the required 8? Also, must it be the case that the $\pm 1$ terms occur in *pairs*, or could we have, say, $A_1 = \dots = A_5 = 0$, $A_6 = A_7 = A_8 = 1$?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your configurations are called valid configurations.

The number of all configurations is $3^8$ (I guess you know why?).

So the invalid configurations are those which have/contain
exactly 0 times or exactly 1 times **a non-zero number** (-1/+1).
Calculate the number of invalid configurations $S$.

Then your answer is $3^8-S$
Can you go on from here?

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I still cant figure it out. Can you give me another hint?